# babelrc config for es7 Decorator not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, decorator, mobx, mobx-react

I've been trying to make MobX work with my React project.
I've followed the `babelrc` config and also installed `transform-decorators-legacy` but it seems like I'm getting `Parsing error: Unexpected character @` after trying to run my project.

Here is my babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

Webpack Dev config:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';

export default {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  noInfo: true,
  entry: [
    './src/webpack-public-path',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    './src/index'
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src`,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      __DEV__: true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.ejs',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true
      },
      inject: true
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'postcss', 'sass?sourceMap']}
    ]
  },
  postcss: ()=> [autoprefixer]
};
```

Anything I missed?

Here is code that gives out the error (Store.js):

```
import { autorun, observable } from 'mobx';

class appStore {
    @observable userSession = { /*error at this line (4:2) at @observable*/
                isUserLogged: false,
                id: 0,
                name: '',
                token: '',
                memberId: 0,
                membershipId: 1000
            }
}
```

Here is my `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jquery": true,
    "mocha": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotes": 0,
    "no-console": 1,
    "no-debugger": 1,
    "no-var": 1,
    "semi": [1, "always"],
    "no-trailing-spaces": 0,
    "eol-last": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "no-alert": 0,
    "no-lone-blocks": 0,
    "jsx-quotes": 1,
    "react/display-name": [ 1, {"ignoreTranspilerName": false }],
    "react/forbid-prop-types": [1, {"forbid": ["any"]}],
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": 0,
    "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": 0,
    "react/jsx-curly-spacing": 1,
    "react/jsx-indent-props": 0,
    "react/jsx-key": 1,
    "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-bind": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-literals": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
    "react/jsx-pascal-case": 1,
    "react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
    "react/no-danger": 1,
    "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-direct-mutation-state": 1,
    "react/no-multi-comp": 1,
    "react/no-set-state": 0,
    "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
    "react/prefer-es6-class": 1,
    "react/prop-types": 1,
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
    "react/require-extension": 1,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
    "react/sort-comp": 1,
    "react/wrap-multilines": 1
  },
  "globals": {
  }
}
```

Error Message:

```
Parse errors in imported module './Store.js': Unexpected character '@' (4:2)  import/namespace
```

Comment: Could you include the code that gives rise to the error? Your `.babelrc` looks correct. You could also try to change the order of `"es2015"` and `"react"`.

Comment: @Tholle , sry for the late reply. I've added the code that gives out the error. Btw, I also tried your suggestion of re-arranging the order of `es2015` & `react` but it still didn't work for me.

Comment: No problem. Silly question: Is your file named `.babelrc` or `babelrc`?

Comment: @Tholle Its named as`.babelrc`... I'm thinking its my `.eslintrc` file? I've added the code to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I fixed the issue.
It was related to my `.eslintrc` file.

I did some searching & found this [link](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4096)

ESLint doesn't natively support experimental ECMAScript language features such as decorators. Therefore we need to install `babel-eslint` to our dev env and add `"parser": "babel-eslint"` to our `.eslintrc` file.

I did that and it resolved my parsing error issue.

Hope it helps anyone out there!